# Get Parent ViewController from within embedded child UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uicontainerview

How do I get a reference to the parent UIViewController from within a controller which is embedded in it using a Container View?

I want to access the **Parent** from within the **Child**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add view controller in container view it is added as child view controller

You can access child it like following way

```
  if let yourVC:YourViewController = self.childViewControllers.first(where: {$0 is yourVC:YourViewController}) as? YourViewController {
        // Here you got it 

    }
```

You can access Parent with    `parent` property of viewController

```
  if let parent = self.navigationController?.parent as? ParentControllerType {

     // Do what you want with the parent.

   }
```

see this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621362-parent

Hope it is helpful

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I want to access the parent from within the child.

Comment: @MuddassirAhmed You can access it with .parent property

Comment: Let me check it now.

Comment: ```
if let parent = self.navigationController?.parent as? ParentControllerType {
            // Do what you want with the parent.
        }
```

Comment: @MuddassirAhmed  you need to check your parent with `if let`  it is good practice . :)

Comment: Great (Y). Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a short and sweet way of doing it: go up the hierarchy until you get the "true" parent, the functional way:

```swift
extension UIViewController {
    var trueParent: UIViewController {
        parent?.trueParent ?? self
    }
}
```